# How to catch users which open application from multiple page

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

In my web application, some users open app in multiple browser page. How can I catch users when they do it?

**Edit about why I need such this thing:** I have a variable named DealerID, carried between pages with session. Some users want that: "While I make my jobs with a DealerID in one page, make other jobs with another DealerID on another page"

I tried to explain. I hope, it will help.

Comment: Don't criminalize your users - opening multiple windows is not a crime!

Comment: Catch them? And do what? I have SO open in two tabs now, should I be worried someone's coming for me? :/

Comment: To take a step back from the immediate issue: Why is it a problem when users open your app in two windows? Does it somehow corrupt the application state?

Comment: A user opening yoru app in multiple browsers is essentially the same as multiple users opening it in single browser. Unless you want to track multiple sessions from the same IP (which is nowhere close to be reliable) you are without luck here

Comment: Don't worry. I want to only number of tabs which a user opened my app at the same time.

Comment: I'm not sure why everyone is so hung up on why. It's entirely possible that there is a specific business need for such behavior.

Comment: @Andrey: When testing an app for concurrency issues, each of my browsers connects through a different proxy, so that tracking by IP fails. It is a reasonable expectation that precise IP tracking is useless.

Comment: @Joel Etherton: E-xactly. The point is to find (and fix) the problem, not mask the symptoms. An analogy: if your car engine is noisy, it may be due to multiple different issues, with different solutions (from "no problem, shift to a higher gear" to "ohs**t, stop and replace $thatpart before it blows up!"); however "oh, noisy you say? Turn up the radio then" is not a real solution as it only masks the problem.

Comment: @Piskvor - To use your own analogy -- if your car is noisy it may be because it is a race car. Not all symptoms are necessarily problems. I have a business case where opening multiple windows can have adverse effects on an application, so I don't find his question so very alarming. I agree that he would do well to isolate the need and attempt to eliminate it, but that doesn't answer his question and, frankly, it is not our choice to make for him.

Comment: Nationwide online bank dont allow you to open multiple tabs!!!

Comment: @Joel occam's razor - answer with the fewest possible assumptions first. Or to continue with the analogy, most people don't drive racing cars.

Comment: @Joel Etherton: You are right - I assumed too much. I don't find the original question alarming, nor am I trying to say "you MUST have state-agnostic pages" - that's indeed not our decision to make; I wanted to ascertain whether this problem is a side effect of business logic, or if it's an artifact of the current implementation. (and yes, I agree that it doesn't answer the question - that's why I asked for more info in a comment)

Comment: @Pete2k: It's usually a tradeoff. Especially in critical apps, the app must proceed only from one valid state through a valid path to another valid state. Forcing one window only is very inconvenient for the user, but makes it much easier to ensure a consistent state - concurrency is hard, especially when you go shopping ;)

Comment: @Dave - I agree. The simplest solution in this case however is to remove all assumptions and simply answer the question at face value. It is not for us to question why he has the need, only to accept that he has the need.

Comment: @Joel Etherton: By answering at face value, we could actually be *inserting* our own assumptions - asking for specifics may make the question clearer. (But I think we're getting rather philosophical now, shall we take it to Meta?)

Comment: @Joel, sorry, it's there I disagree. He might have a valid reason for doing it, but equally there might be a better way to solve the original problem while still letting users use his product the way *they* want. Doesn't hurt to get more information in this case and may help him provide a better experience to users overall.

Comment: @Piskvor, @Dave, @Greg: You all 3 misconstrue my meaning. I'm not saying asking is a bad idea. More information is always useful. My problem is/was/always will be the individuals who say don't do it or condemn the OP's need without considering any of the points you guys mention. Several people were quick to comment negatively without offering solutions or alternatives.

Comment: @Joel Etherton: Ah, okay, I have misunderstood you - I apologize. It seems we are violently in agreement then ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically you cannot find out who has opened more than one page (`HTTP` is connection-less) unless they tell you themselves !

I'm thinking it as a matter of executive work (how to do it efficiently) rather than the best technical tamper-proof solution. So:

Put a little `AJAX` control (`JavaScript` code) on the page which works as a signaling component from a client and says Blah..Blah....

Use `Session` objects (`ASP.NET` would take care of correct session key/value for you, just use it at server side) and if there are two signals from a single client, you have catched(!) them as you wish. It's possible for a power user to disable this defense mechanism but you can raise the price by implementing it more complicated.

I suggest don't react to cheating immediately. Flag the user in your business logic and show the bill later. This is more effective i.e, what StackOverFlow.com do `:)`

Comment: `Some users want that: "While I make my jobs with a DealerID in one page, make other jobs with another DealerID on another page"`  So the accepted answer is to not give the users the functionality they want?

Answer (score 3):

The real thing you need to focus on is fixing your application to support multiple tabs/pages.

What I suggest you do is store the session data into the page of the application and reconstruct it when the page submits it back to the server.  That way each page can use the same session variables to pass the page along, without it creating side effects in the system.

Session data really should be truly global data, that can be referenced without worry.  If you have "long persisting" data that is created with the assumption that only one page will ever be using it, then you are going to have some trouble.

Answer (score 3):

**Session is the wrong thing to use for this use case.**  You should have the instance of the browser tell you  what the DealerID is during each request.  You can accomplish this with the query string, viewstate, with a dropdownlist/field on the page on the page, etc.

Rationale: Session is tied to all instances of the browser through a shared cookie, which causes this problem.  Query String or ViewState, or a field on the page tie the data to a specific instance of browser window.  By using this method, you're eliminating the problem completely and using the technology as it was designed.

Comment: I seriously feel like I'm taking crazy pills here.  If the Session is causing you problem, don't use it.  It's the easiest answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would bind a token to the objects you are sending to the browser and store them in a database with reference to the user and the object they requested.

I would send the token with each request and embed it into a hidden field on the page. And then hook the token on any postback with javascript. If the token comes back more than once you have your extra tab!

Answer (score 1):

Given that you want to count the number of tabs that a user has open with you application at the same time, the issues is that there really isn't a good way of doing it. The best way to do it would likely to be to run something locally, but since different browsers are coded differently, there isn't a good way to get the titles short of knowing which browser the user is using and making an API call to find out (if one is available!).

If you just need a basic, rough, estimate as to what the count might be. You could try setting a cookie when the application is loaded (loading it in a new tab would have to cause the cookie to be reset) and cross-referencing a GUID for each session with the IP address. However, this would never be quite accurate since multiple users could be on the same IP address, they could be using more than one browser, sessions could timeout, etc.